# Clarify this proof: why $(u_j)$ is bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am in trouble with this paper (see the attached picture).
[image]

Almost everything in this page is clear for me, except the last sentence "Combining $(2.16)$ and $(2.23)$, we obtain $(2.18)$".

Could someone please help me to understand why $(2.16)$ and $(2.23)$ implies $(2.18)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparantly the proof uses properties of $\mu$ and $f$ that are not mentioned in these pictures.

Comment: @daw could you please suggest me something? I’m desperately trying to understand it. As it is written, it seems that only $(2.16)$ and $(2.23)$ are involved here.